# Record type where values are the same as a defined interface but as an array

Tags: typescript, types, record

I have an interface where all properties have a base type:

```
interface Types {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: boolean
}
```

And I would like to have a `Database` type which looks the same as the `Types` interface, but with types as arrays instead of base types.

Like this (it's just a representation, as this will be a constructed type):

```
{
    a: number[],
    b: string[],
    c: boolean[]
}
```

---

What I tried is:

```
type Database<Key extends keyof Types> = Record<Key, Array<Types[Key]>>
```

I thought the generic type would be a "silent type" but I actually have to give it as an argument when I want to use the `Database` type... and that's not what I want.

I would like the `Database` type to be usable as is.

---

Solution:

```
interface Types {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: boolean
}

type ValueToArray<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Array<T[K]>;
};

type Database = ValueToArray<Types>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```js
type ValueToArray<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Array<T[K]>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks obvious now ^^